# Convert a datetime64 column into datetime.date when applying .values.tolist() to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need to convert a dataframe to a list, and one of my columns is of type `datetime64`, but when I apply `values.tolist()` in the dataframe, it gets converted to `Timestamp`, and I want it to be `datetime.date`.

This dataframe is obtained from a Google Sheet that is previously read:

```
def get_dataframe_from_sheet(spreadsheet_id, sheet_name, sheet_range):
    range_name = '{}!{}'.format(sheet_name, sheet_range)
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])
    col_names = values.pop(0)

    df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=col_names)

    for col in col_names:
        if col in ('forecast_month'):
            df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], infer_datetime_format=True)
            df[col] = df.apply()
        else:
            df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')

    return df

short_term_df = get_dataframe_from_sheet(SHORT_TERM_SPREADSHEET_ID, SHEET_NAME, COLUMNS)
```

However, when I apply the following:

```
LIST__SHORT_TERM_FORECAST_SEASON_ADJ_OCC = short_term_df[base_columns + ['season_adj_occ']].values.tolist()
```

the values for the column `forecast_month` are of type `Timestamp`, and I need `datetime.date`. How can I achieve this? I have read several questions and their answers, but it seems they do not work properly.

**Example:**

This is what I am getting from the function `get_dataframe_from_sheet`:

```
    property_id  beds forecast_month  rent_growth  baseline_occ  \
0           329     1     2017-02-01         0.02      0.953623   
1           329     1     2017-03-01         0.02      0.953623   
2           329     1     2017-04-01         0.02      0.953623   
3           329     1     2017-05-01         0.02      0.953623   
4           329     1     2017-06-01         0.02      0.953623   
5           329     1     2017-07-01         0.02      0.953623   
6           329     1     2017-08-01         0.02      0.953623   
7           329     1     2017-09-01         0.02      0.953623   
8           329     1     2017-10-01         0.02      0.953623   
9           329     1     2017-11-01         0.02      0.953623   
10          329     1     2017-12-01         0.02      0.953623   
11          329     1     2018-01-01         0.02      0.953623   
12          329     1     2018-02-01         0.02      0.953623   
13          329     1     2018-03-01         0.02      0.953623   
14          329     1     2018-04-01         0.02      0.953623   
15          329     1     2018-05-01         0.02      0.953623   
16          329     1     2018-06-01         0.02      0.953623   
17          329     1     2018-07-01         0.02      0.953623   
18          329     1     2018-08-01         0.02      0.953623   
19          329     1     2018-09-01         0.02      0.953623   
20          329     1     2018-10-01         0.02      0.953623   
21          329     1     2018-11-01         0.02      0.953623   
22          329     1     2018-12-01         0.02      0.953623
```

and this when I apply `.values.tolist()`:

```
[[329,
  1,
  Timestamp('2017-02-01 00:00:00'),
  0.02,
  0.95362261,
  0.9927,
  1.0048,
  0.9581999984999999,
  0.082725,
  0.082725,
  0.0016545000000000002],
 [329,
  1,
  Timestamp('2017-03-01 00:00:00'),
  0.02,
  0.95362261,
  1.0006,
  1.004,
  0.9574371004000001,
  0.08338333332999999,
  0.1661083333,
  0.003322166667], ...
]
```

Comment: show a small reprex with your data bro

Comment: @Noobie, I just updated my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
df['forecast_month_alt'] = df['forecast_month'].dt.date
```

Comment: I just tried that a minute ago, and yes it works as I expected. Thank you.